# Github Actions variables point to fork parent

Tags: github-actions

I've forked a project:
[image]

and I'm setting up a CI definition on non master branches with these final steps:

```
- name: Zip the release
  uses: papeloto/action-zip@v1
  with:
    files: README.md LICENSE *.dll nfive.yml nfive.lock fxmanifest.lua index.html config/
    dest: ${{ github.workspace }}\nfive.zip

- name: Attach Zip as build artifact
  uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
  with:
    name: nfive
    path: ${{ github.workspace }}\nfive.zip
```

Why does github.workspace point to the original repository NFive\NFive?
[image]

So, if run echo ${{ github.workspace }} it definitely shows the parent repository, but to make this even more difficult if I change directory to my organisation name and forked repository name I get this:

[image]

which is the output of these steps:

```
- run: echo ${{ github.workspace }}

- name: Move files to artifact folder
  shell: pwsh
  run: |
    cd D:\a\HTB-5M\NFive
    mkdir Build        
    Move-Item -Path README.md,LICENSE,*.dll,nfive.yml,nfive.lock,fxmanifest.lua,index.html,config -Destination Build
```

I don't have access to the parent path because I'm not a contributor, which is why I forked in the first place, so why does Github assume github.workspace should map to the parent?

=== Udate ===

So I reforked to my user account rather than the organisation I used and added a workflow step to just display the github.workspace variable and it definitely says the parent workspace D:\a\NFive\NFive

[image]

I tried changing the path in the nfive.yml

[image]

Same outcome

[image]

Deleting the nfive.yml doesn't change anything. I think the nfive.yml is actually used in the CI / CD pipelines the original authors configured on appveyor so it isn't going to affect anything here.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't pointing to the fork parent repo, it's because the `github.workspace` variable follows this format: `/home/runner/work/my-repo-name/my-repo-name`.

That's the reason why NFive appears twice, it's **NOT** refering to NFive username / organization, but twice to the NFive **repository name**.

---

This is explained on the github documentation about [default environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environment-variables#default-environment-variables)

[image]

I [forked the repository](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/NFive) as well and I don't get any error when running [this workflow](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/NFive/blob/features/CI/.github/workflows/ci.yml).

Here is the [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/NFive/runs/3036158993?check_suite_focus=true) output with the [generated `.zip` file artifact](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/NFive/actions/runs/1018077815).

Comment: I just tried the same thing you did but I get the same error. I also tried deleting the file altogether, not sure why it’s even needed, same error. Actually if you look at you run in the echo step it still shows D:\a\NFive\NFive

Comment: I don't understand either how it can work on my fork and not on yours 

Comment: The weirdest part is it's D:\a\NFive\NFive in your case, yet the zip is still being generated and attached to the run

Comment: Actually, I don't think it is an error, it's because the `github.workspace` follow this format: `/home/runner/work/my-repo-name/my-repo-name`. That's the reason why `NFive` appears twice, it's NOT refering to NFive username / org, but twice to the NFive **repository name**. This is explained on the github documentation about [default environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environment-variables#default-environment-variables). I updated the answer above.